# Proving De Morgan's Law for Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am being asked to prove the following statement but I am getting stuck. This is the statement:

A\ (B ∪ C) = (A\B) ∩ (A\C).

To prove this equality, I began by taking x to be an element of A\ (B ∪ C). This means that x is an element of A  and x is not an element of (B ∪ C). After this point I get stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the next questions to ask are "is $x \in A - B$?" And "is $x \in A - C$?" If the answer to both of these questions is yes, then you are in good shape.

Comment: Because "$x$ is an element of $(B \cup C)$" means that either $x \in B $ or $x \in C$, "$x$ is not an element of $(B \cup C)$" means that neither $x \in B $ nor $x \in C$, i.e. $x \notin B $ and $x \notin C$.

Comment: Then you need to show the opposite inclusion.

Comment: As you say, you get "$x$ is not in $B \cup C$". What does this mean? Try negating the statement $x$ is in $B \cup C$. Maybe first re-write "$x$ in $B \cup C$" as "$x$ in $B$ or $x$ in $C$", and then try negating.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I've been able to prove that direction of the equality.

Comment: For the opposite direction, I have the following. Is it correct?

Comment: Suppose x ∈ (A\B) ∩ (A\C). Then this implies x ∈ (A\B) and x ∈ (A\C). If x ∈ (A\B) then we have x ∈ A and x ∉ B. This also means that if x ∈ (A\C) then we have x ∈ A and x ∉ C. So we can easily see that x ∈ A\ (B∪C).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA does my solution above look correct for the second direction?

Answer (score 1):

To continue the direction started in the post: Since $x\notin B\cup C$, we have that $x\notin B$ and $x\notin C$.  So $x\in A\backslash B$ and $x\in A\backslash C$.  So $x\in (A\backslash B)\cap (A\backslash C)$